# XOR operator is not giving expected results?

Tags: python, operators, xor

I am familiar with using the 'and', 'not' and 'or' operators in Python and I have just learnt how the 'XOR' operator works.

But, it doesn't seem to work when I coded this:

```
a = 2
b = 12

if a == 2 ^ b == 12:
    print("You must be broken") # because TRUE XOR TRUE IS FALSE

if a == 10 ^ b > 12:
    print("You must also be broken") # because FALSE XOR FALSE IS FALSE

if a < 10 ^ b > 13:
    print("This should print because TRUE XOR FALSE IS TRUE")

if a > 3 ^ b == 12:
    print("This should print because FALSE XOR TRUE IS TRUE")
```

The program does not print anything out?

Comment: Look at [Python's operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Also keep in mind that in python `A == B == C` is the same as `A == B and B == C`, so `a == 2 ^ b == 12` is the same as `a == (2^b) == 12` which is the same as `a == (2^b) and (2^b) == 12`.

Comment: While it happens to work, you should not apply bitwise operators to booleans. A more logical and readable version of an XOR would be `if (a == 2) != (b == 12)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are misunderstanding [Python's operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

This condition:

```
a < 10 ^ b > 13
```

means

```
a < (10^b) > 13
```

which means

```
(a < 10^b) and (10^b > 13)
```

So it is false.

Presumably you mean:

```
(a < 10) ^ (b > 13)
```

Similarly for your other conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, you will get your aswer:

```
if (a == 2) ^ (b == 12):
    print("You must be broken") # because TRUE XOR TRUE IS FALSE

if (a == 10) ^ (b > 12):
    print("You must also be broken") # because FALSE XOR FALSE IS FALSE

if (a < 10) ^ (b > 13):
    print("This should print because TRUE XOR FALSE IS TRUE")

if (a > 3) ^ (b == 12):
    print("This should print because FALSE XOR TRUE IS TRUE")
```

This happened because those operators do not think as you do.
Look at useful link that Grant posted in comments.

Comment: https://thehelloworldprogram.com/python/python-operators-order-precedence/ if you would like to know more

Comment: @GrantMcCloskey Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You missed parenthesis, check [operators precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), the operator ^ has more priority than ==

a simple fix:

```
a = 2
b = 12
if ( a == 2 ) ^ ( b == 12 ):
    print("You must be broken") # because TRUE XOR TRUE IS FALSE

if ( a == 10) ^( b > 12 ):
    print("You must also be broken") # because FALSE XOR FALSE IS FALSE

if ( a < 10) ^ (b > 13):
    print("This should print because TRUE XOR FALSE IS TRUE")

if  ( a > 3) ^( b == 12):
    print("This should print because FALSE XOR TRUE IS TRUE")
```